# Connection problem with phpseclib Net SSH2

Tags: php, phpseclib, net-ssh, wamp64

I am having problems with phpseclib Net SSH2 libraries, the connection to the server is impossible, I tried to find a solution but I can not find it.

Notice: Error reading from socket in C:\wamp64\www\v5\library\backend\global\class\lib\Net\SSH2.php on line 3494

Notice: Connection closed by server in C:\wamp64\www\v5\library\backend\global\class\lib\Net\SSH2.php on line 1497

```
include('lib/Net/SSH2.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
     echo $ssh->isConnected() ? 'bad username or password' : 'unable to establish connection';
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
echo $ssh->getLog();
```

Here are the recovered error logs:

```
<-
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:4f:70:65:6e:53:53:48:5f  SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
00000010  36:2e:37:70:31:20:44:65:62:69:61:6e:2d:35:2b:64  6.7p1 Debian-5+d
00000020  65:62:38:75:38:0d:0a                             eb8u8..

->
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli
00000010  62:5f:31:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:2c:20  b_1.0 (openssl, 
00000020  67:6d:70:29:0d:0a                                gmp)..

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.1796, network: 0s)
00000000  d8:18:e9:65:85:2a:0e:6c:0c:3d:be:0b:b7:89:94:92  ...e.*.l.=......
00000010  00:00:00:7e:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d  ...~diffie-hellm
00000020  61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64  an-group1-sha1,d
00000030  69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72  iffie-hellman-gr
00000040  6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69  oup14-sha1,diffi
00000050  65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d  e-hellman-group-
00000060  65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69  exchange-sha1,di
00000070  66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f  ffie-hellman-gro
00000080  75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32  up-exchange-sha2
00000090  35:36:00:00:00:29:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32  56...)rsa-sha2-2
000000a0  35:36:2c:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c  56,rsa-sha2-512,
000000b0  73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73:68:2d:64:73:73:00  ssh-rsa,ssh-dss.
000000c0  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d  ..........9hmac-
000000d0  73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68  sha2-256,hmac-sh
000000e0  61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c  a1-96,hmac-sha1,
000000f0  68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63  hmac-md5-96,hmac
00000100  2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61  -md5...9hmac-sha
00000110  32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d  2-256,hmac-sha1-
00000120  39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61  96,hmac-sha1,hma
00000130  63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64  c-md5-96,hmac-md
00000140  35:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e  5....none....non
00000150  65:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00        e.............
```

Thanks you for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using phpseclib 1.0. As such you need to set the include_path, like so:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib');
```

phpseclib builds the list of encryption algorithms that it supports for SSH2 based on what can be loaded or auto-loaded. In your case it's not finding any encryption algorithms, suggesting that none are able to be loaded / auto-loaded. Presumably because of your include_path issues.

Comment: Yes, it was an include problem. Fixed now, thanks you!